# ffmpeg stream snapshot at clocktime

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

Im trying to make snapshot of RTSP stream every hour (at clock hour).

I successfully segmented video files by the hour by this command:

```
ffmpeg -i <input stream> -f segment -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_time 3600 <output files>
```

But it doesnt work for sapshot:

```
ffmpeg -i i <input stream> -f segment -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_time 3600 -segment_format singlejpeg <output files>
```

It creates mjpeg video instead of snapshot.

Maybe there is another way to do snapshot every real-time hour?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you actually using for `<output files>` in both commands?

Comment: in first case 
`C:\video%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M.mp4`
in second case
`С:\snapshot_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.jpeg`